# How to find all occurences of multiple strings?

Tags: regex

I have the example String:

```
There are from {d} to {d} {s} balls available. Average of {f} balls.
```

I want to find all occurences of those tags: `{d}`, `{f}` and `{s}`.

What would be the regex pattern for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do like this,

```
\{[dsf]\}
```

- `\{`, `\}` matches  literal `{`, `}` symbols.
- `[dsf]` character class which matches a single character from the given list , ie `d` or `s` or `f`

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex with global modifier :

```
/\{[dfs]\}/g
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/hZ6gO4/1

`[dfs]` is a character class and will match one of the characters within it!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "There are from 5 to 7 red balls available. Average of 10.3 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 3 to 6 blue balls available. Average of 3.5 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 4 to 7 green balls available. Average of 5.6 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 6 to 8 yellow balls available. Average of 16.7 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 4 to 9 purple balls available. Average of 10.4 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 6 to 8 orange balls available. Average of 17.6 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 7 to 7 white balls available. Average of 18.6 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 4 to 6 black balls available. Average of 3.7 balls.\n" +
                "There are from 5 to 9 tan balls available. Average of 5.6 balls.\n";

            string pattern = @"(?'min'\d+) to (?'max'\d+) (?'color'\w+)[^\d]+(?'average'\d+\.\d+)";

            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches(input);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                string CSV = string.Join(",", new string[] {
                    match.Groups["min"].Value, match.Groups["max"].Value, match.Groups["color"].Value, match.Groups["average"].Value
                });
                results.Add(CSV);
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```